# Selenium - Error Launching Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

When I call System.setProperty() on line 11 I get this error

> ```
> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Syntax error on token ",", < expected
>   - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
>   - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
>    MethodHeaderName
>   - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
>    QualifiedName
>   - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
> ```

I know that the path to my chromedriver.exe is correct because I checked. I think it's just the placement of my System.setProperty().

---

Can someone help me with how to fix this so I don't get an error

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;


public class BugLogin {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws Exception {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("url");
}

public boolean bug() {
    WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.id("")); 
    while(true){
        if(test.getText().equals("text")){
            driver.findElement(By.id(""));
            driver.findElement(By.id("")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys("text");

            driver.findElement(By.id(""));
            driver.findElement(By.id("")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys("text");

            driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();
            break;
        }
        else{
            driver.navigate().back();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, as per provided code, you initiate the chromeDriver object but using the driver object? where you initiate driver object? secondly, you are using only "@BeforeTest" and there is no "@Test" is it not required as per ur requirement? i am confused, let me know, what ur trying here? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the below statement:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
```

> Reason: You cannot use  a statement containing executable code outside
>   the class methods and only declare and initialize an identifier in
>   definition.

Defining the ChromeDriver in definition and initializing it later in @BeforeTest may solve your problem.

```
WebDriver chromeDriver;

@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
  chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("url");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not place your setup in your `setup` method?

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
    chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("url");
}
```

Comment: I did but then the driver object becomes localized within the method and i can't call it anywhere else outside of that method.

Comment: No, you keep the driver as a class parameter

Comment: I left it as a parameter and then added it in the setup() method but still got the same error